# SugarCRM 6.2 CE Imap module selfsigned certificate error

Tags: ssl, imap, sugarcrm

Can somebody help to solve such problem ?

I have installed **Sugar CRM 6.2 CE**. 
Everything is going ok, but incoming **imap** mail doesn't work.

I see the following popup when press 'Test settings':

Certificate failure for mail.zzzz.com: **self signed** certificate: /C=US/ST=Someprovince/L=Sometown/O=none/OU=none/CN=localhost/emailAddress=webaster@localhost
Please check your settings and try again.

Hope you will help me to find solution.
Alexey

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the self signed root CA certificate you can install it in your operation system certificate store.

As an example on Ubuntu server:

- copy your self signed CA certificate to /usr/share/ca-certificates/
- execute "dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates" as root (choose yes if you're asked to install new certificates)
- choose your CA certificate in the following dialog

On Windows you can try to

- doubleclick the CA file
- or install the certificate trough Internet Explorer settings (as far as I know)